# Execute script before shutting down

Tags: scripts, shutdown

When I shut down my computer I want to show some pending tasks that I have to do before leaving the office...  I did a local application to manage those tasks, basically I just want to run a command, and shut down after I kill the app executed.

Comment: May be useful for future users: http://askubuntu.com/a/747556/295286

Answer (score 7):

You could add your command to the file `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` before the `exit 0` line.

Comment: If I go to "Log Out" option it executes fine, But If I press shutdown appear almost instantaneous ubuntu purple logout screen and executes the script (in the screen where appears ubuntu logo with 5 little balls).
(tested with sleep 20).

Comment: The "Are you sure you want to shutdown" dialog is located here: /usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper and a part of the indicator-session package witch is written in C/C++ so its pretty hard to edit. You might have more luck asking at some gnome-guru mailinglist ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by creating a script in /etc/rc0.d (for shutdown) and /etc/rc6.d (for reboot).
To do this, run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/rc0.d/K01mycustomscript
```

Edit your shutdown script in the text editor then run:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc0.d/K01mycustomscript
```

And if you want it to run on reboot also then run this:

```
sudo cp /etc/rc0.d/K01mycustomscript /etc/rc6.d/K01mycustomscript
```

Source: [this forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=436346)

Comment: From his description it sounds likes he wants to invoke a graphical app, so it needs access to the xserver. In this case using init-scripts does not work.

Comment: Yeah... as @sepp2k says, script is running outside xserver :(

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a question for superuser.com to me. Anyway, after some [Googling I found How to run a script on logout?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=185261) which says to add the script to $HOME/.bash_logout.

If that doesn't work, add

```
$HOME/.bash_logout
```

to /etc/gdm/PostSession/Default so it executes the logout script properly.

Seeing as before shutdown the user is logged off anyway, this should cover both bases.

Comment: Since he probably doesn't want the script to run every time, he logs out of bash (i.e. every time he closes a terminal window), I don't think it's a good idea to write the command into .bash_logout. However writing it into PostSession/Default looks like a good idea to me.

Comment: Already have this file, but looks like it is not working (I put sleep 20 and it didn't wait to shutdown.)

Comment: .bash_logout will not run when you close a terminal, it will only run when you log out from a terminal-login-session (ie. if you logout a `real` TTY) and not when you logout of gnome.

Comment: Why would this be a question for superuser? If the question is about Ubuntu it's on topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `./app-to-run && sudo shutdown -h now` the computer should shut down once app-to-run is done.

Comment: This would be a very crude shutdown. You rather want to call the desktop shutdown script instead.

Comment: The sudo might ask the user to type the password in case app-to-run is long enough... So it'll never shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Almost same answer than Tommy Brunn but without the risk to hang with being asked the root password :

```
sudo sh -c "./app-to-run; shutdown -h now"
```