# Auto-start Upstart User Jobs on boot

Tags: upstart, services

I've enabled [Upstart User Jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#enabling) and configured a few jobs. These jobs can be started/stopped by the respective user and all is well. However the `start on` stanza doesn't seem to have effect:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
```

Everytime the system is rebooted, I'd have to ssh into the machine and `start [job name]`. How can I force the system to also start those user jobs?

Comment: have you tried run level 6? It is specifically for reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Following is an upstart script that worked for me to allow user jobs to start at system startup. Without it I could not get them to work either.

```bsh
author 'Bradley Ayers'
description 'Enables user job "start on" stanzas to be honored at boot'

task
start on starting rc-sysinit

script
cat /etc/passwd | while read line
do
    user=`echo $line | cut -d: -f1`
    home=`echo $line | cut -d: -f6`
    if [ -d "$home/.init" ]
        then
        sudo -u $user initctl status rc-sysinit
    fi
done
end script
```

---

Source: I got the script from: [Enabling Upstart user jobs to start at boot](http://bradleyayers.blogspot.com/2012/04/enabling-upstart-user-jobs-to-start-at.html)

Comment: But this would only be a workaround and not a real solution...

Answer (score 2):

The `start on` stanza seems not to work in all variations as I already explained here:
[Safely close virtualbox machine on host reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101294/safely-close-virtualbox-machine-on-host-reboot/278705#278705)

Use this here:

```
start on started rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem to work for me. After a reboot, the process isn't started.